# How to find placement of a point in degrees on a circle's circumference given coordinates

Tags: math, coordinates, trigonometry, geometry, degrees

Who is a math wiz and wants to check my math?

I'm trying to find the placement of a `point(x,y)` on the circumference of a circle in degrees. If I use `x=radius*cos(Q)+xOrigin`, I end up with `arccos((x/2)-xOrigin) = Q` which gives me the angle in radians. Then I go `D = Q(180/Pi)` to get degrees, but I keep coming up about 3-5 degrees off of target.

What's up with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula for Q should be

```
Q = acos((x-xOrigin)/radius)
```

Note that `acos` returns an angle between 0 and pi; if the angle is in the third or fourth quadrant you'll need to subtract the angle from 2 * pi.

Without knowing the actual values that are coming up wrong, it's hard to tell if that's the only problem. Your conversion from radians to degrees is correct.

Comment: Thanks! So if the point is in quadrant 3 or 4 it would be Q = acos((x-xOrigin)/radius) + Pi?

Comment: So I'm having an issue still with this. Say My circle has a radius of 2 and is situated at (0,0). To find the angle in degrees of a point at x=1.41, y=-1(or any negative value in this case - only using it to determine quadrant) I would use D=(acos((1.41-0)/2)+Pi)*(180/Pi) correct? I keep getting 225.19 for this, it should be in quadrant 4 and I think it should be 135 instead, since the corresponding equation (minus adding Pi) gives me 45.17 for positive values of y. Am I losing my mind?

Comment: Drat. I gave you the wrong conversion for third/fourth quadrant. Sorry about that. The correct conversion would be `Q = 2*pi - acos((x-xOrigin)/radius)`.

Comment: So in the example you gave, the angle (which will be in the fourth quadrant) will be `360 - 45.17 = 314.83` degrees.

Answer (score 0):

Most modern programming languages have `atan2()` somewhere, which takes a rise and a run and spits out the angle in radians in all four quadrants.